# How to play audio by absolute path? - android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I save audio to internal storage and get absolute path. Looks like this: `/data/user/0/com.example.example/files/example/605f7c482b0cb60c71832080.mp3`. When I put this path into mediaplayer it doesn't work. How can I play audio using this path?

**Edit:**
Code snippet:

```
audioUrl = "/data/user/0/com.example.example/files/example/605f7c482b0cb60c71832080.mp3";
try {
   mPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), Uri.parse(audioUrl));
   mPlayer.prepareAsync();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the snippet of code that you tried?

Comment: have you called mPlayer.play()

Comment: @DayaAL, yes. But it doesn't matter, cause the error is that the file is not found.

Comment: Since that is not a valid `Uri`, it is unlikely to `parse()` well. Use `Uri.fromFile()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should add permission to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```